Possibility to see/explore the raw data for the charts in Looker Studio
I am creating a Looker Studio report that consist of few charts based on a one datasource with the huge number of columns. The cross filtering between these charts are enabled. Need to have a posibility for each chart to let viewer to explore the raw data that are shown on this chart according to current filtering.
The only one idea I have at the moment is to somehow link two reports. First will show charts and the second will have a table with the raw data. But how I can pass current state of all the filters from the first report to be applied in the second?
